# How To Associate A Custom Value With Each Address Book Contact

Tags: android

I want to have a boolean value associated with all of my contacts in the address book.  This boolean value will indicate whether a contact is part of my team or not.  If there is no boolean value associated with the contact, the value would default to 'false'.  I also want to show all my contacts in a list view with a check mark associated with the boolean value (defaulting to 'false' if there is no value).

Question: What would be a good approach to store the boolean value associated with each contact in a manner that I can create a cursor that has all the contacts and the boolean value associated with each contact.

Since there are a lot of contacts, I want to make sure that the time taken to create this cursor (to be shown in the list view) is as less as possible.  I have been looking at the Contacts content provider but so far I have not been able to come up with a good approach.

Thanks!
Prasanna